# Why enable A20 line in Protected Mode?

Tags: linux, assembly, linux-kernel, x86, operating-system

In the bootloader's assembly source file of Linux 0.01, the A20 line is enabled.

From `boot/boot.s`:

```
| that was painless, now we enable A20

call     empty_8042
mov al,#0xD1

...
```

Afterwards the bootloader jumps into Protected Mode.

In Real Mode, enabling the A20 line grants us an address space expansion of 64 KiB - 16 bytes.

In Protected Mode, the address bus is unlocked automatically.

Why does the bootloader enable the A20 address line when the jump to Protected Mode would do that anyway?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> In Real Mode, enabling the A20 line grants us an address space expansion of 64 KiB - 16 bytes.

Correct, in Real Mode (on a 286+) you could set a segment register to `0xFFFF`, which would allow you to access memory up to `(0xFFFF << 4) + 64K`.

> In Protected Mode, the address bus is unlocked automatically.

Protected mode is a CPU mode, so it doesn't "unlock" the bus, it simply allows additional address space to be used, which requires more pins on the address bus.

> Why does the bootloader enable the A20 address line when the jump to Protected Mode would do that anyway?

Because it wouldn't.  "A20" generally refers to a hardware hack, added in the PC-AT, that needs to be disabled before protected mode will function as expected.

First, recall that old old CPUs (through the 80186) could only access up to 1 MiB of memory, and thus had 20 address lines (A0 - A19). Some very old software took advantage of the fact that memory accesses above 1 MiB would *wrap* to the lower memory.

When the 286 added more address lines, IBM didn't want to break the compatibility with this old software, so they did the unimaginable: They put an *external* gate on the 21st address line (A20), and left it off by default, re-enabling the wrap-around behavior, so old software would still function correctly. So the 286 itself knows nothing about this hack - it is external to the CPU. To the CPU, A20 is no different than any other address line.

This gate, (the A20 gate), is controlled by a GPIO pin on the keyboard controller IC. Thus, you need to enable it before going into protected mode. If you didn't, (and say you flat-mapped all 4GB of physical memory), then as [Micheal Petch indicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33827474/why-enable-a20-line-in-protected-mode/33827632?noredirect=1#comment55429926_33827632), "every odd numbered megabyte region will be inaccessible. So 1mb-2mb will actually reference 0-1mb, 3mb-4mb will reference 2mb-3mb etc."
See also:

- [A20 Line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A20_line) (Wikipedia)

Comment: 1. So Protected Mode won't enable A20 but all other address lines associated with the mode (16-bit -> A0 - A23, 32-bit -> A0 - A31), right? 2. As far as I can tell, "'A20 line' [...] needs to be disabled before protected mode will function as expected" and "you need to enable it [A20 line] before going into protected mode" contradict each other. Could you clarify that, please? 3. What do you mean by "This is not accurate."?

Comment: @cad The A20 gate is an *external* hack. If it weren't for the IBM PC-AT designers adding it, we wouldn't be having this conversation today. The 286 itself doesn't treat A20 any differently.  **2.** I was saying that the "hack" that is A20 wraparound needs to be disabled... by enabling the A20 gate.

Comment: Got it, thanks. Regarding the "inaccuracy", I explicitly said Real Mode because I thought it can address only 1 MiB + 64 KiB - 10 bytes anyway but Unreal Mode just came to my mind. With the "unlock", that's just wrong terminology I think. BTW, I think you have a zero too much in what's supposed to be the begin of the second MiB of RAM.

Comment: @cad Ah, I understand now. Yes, you are correct, in Real Mode (on a 286+) you could set a segment register to 0xFFFF, which would allow you to access memory up to (0xFFFF << 4) + 64K. And thanks, I've corrected that address.

Comment: @cad It is not actually required to enable the A20 line. If you don't though then the effect is that every odd numbered megabyte region will be inaccessible. So 1mb-2mb will actually reference 0-1mb, 3mb-4mb will reference 2mb-3mb etc. Without enabling the A20 bit, that address line will always be zero. Of course that is pretty useless, but is still allowed.

Comment: @cad A footnote might be that the original versions of DOS required the wrap around to be compatible with CP/M OSes by allowing some compatibility with CALL 5 mechanism that was used to make BDOS (basic disk operating system) calls on CP/M

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thanks, I quoted your explanation of the aliasing, as it was more accurate than mine (I forgot it would happen at *every* odd MB).